# Not getting company names from LinkedIn people API

Tags: linkedin-api

I recently noticed that, when I access some users via the peopla API, I do not get the company names in their positions.

E.g.
I ask: `/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,positions:(title,summary,start-date,end-date,company:(id,name)))`

I get:

```
{
  "firstName": "xxxxx",
  "id": "WzdY2z96Tw",
  "lastName": "xxxx",
  "positions": {
    "_total": 12,
    "values": [
      {
        "company": {},
        "startDate": {
          "month": 4,
          "year": 2015
        }
      },
      {
        "company": {"id": 1970},
        "endDate": {
          "month": 11,
          "year": 2014
        },
        "startDate": {
          "month": 7,
          "year": 2008
        }
      },
      {
        "company": {},
        "endDate": {
          "month": 7,
          "year": 2008
        },
        "startDate": {
          "month": 4,
          "year": 2006
        }
      },
      {
        "company": {"id": 1159270},
        "endDate": {
          "month": 1,
          "year": 2006
        },
        "startDate": {
          "month": 5,
          "year": 2004
        }
      },
      {
        "company": {"id": 106859},
        "endDate": {
          "month": 5,
          "year": 2004
        },
        "startDate": {
          "month": 1,
          "year": 2003
        }
      },
      {
        "company": {"id": 106859},
        "endDate": {
          "month": 1,
          "year": 2003
        },
        "startDate": {
          "month": 5,
          "year": 2001
        }
      },
      {
        "company": {},
        "endDate": {
          "month": 5,
          "year": 2001
        },
        "startDate": {
          "month": 1,
          "year": 1999
        }
      },    
      {
        "company": {},
        "endDate": {"year": 1998},
        "startDate": {"year": 1995}
      },
      {
        "company": {},
        "endDate": {"year": 1995},
        "startDate": {"year": 1994}
      },
      {
        "company": {},
        "endDate": {"year": 1994},
        "startDate": {"year": 1993}
      },
      {
        "company": {},
        "endDate": {"year": 1993},
        "startDate": {"year": 1991}
      },
      {
        "company": {},
        "endDate": {"year": 1991},
        "startDate": {"year": 1988}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

(I changed the name to x'es for privacy reasons)
So, as you can see, I don't get the company names back.
I do get the company names back for other users.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a support request

Comment: According to recent LinkedIn policies, they indicate that all questions on LinkedIn should be posted on StackOverflow, see https://developer.linkedin.com/support . They indicate that they will look at all questions on Stackoverflow with the tag linkedin. So, my understanding is that this should be here?

Answer (score -1):

`/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,positions)` enough for retrieving company names.